# ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

When i go to my wordpress dashboard. i get a `ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined` when i look at the error it says its on this code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function() {
    tinymce.on( 'AddEditor', function( event ) {
        event.editor.on( 'BeforeSetContent', function( event ) {
            var editor = event.target;
            Object.keys( editor.schema.elements ).forEach( function( key, index ) {
                editor.schema.elements[ key ].attributes['markdown'] = {};
                editor.schema.elements[ key ].attributesOrder.push( 'markdown' );
            } );
        } );
    }, true );
} );
</script>
```

The tinymce is included above this code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCEPreInit = {
            baseURL: "https://my-url/wp-includes/js/tinymce",
            suffix: ".min",
                        mceInit: {},
            qtInit: {'replycontent':{id:"replycontent",buttons:"strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,close"}},
            ref: {plugins:"",theme:"modern",language:""},
            load_ext: function(url,lang){var sl=tinymce.ScriptLoader;sl.markDone(url+'/langs/'+lang+'.js');sl.markDone(url+'/langs/'+lang+'_dlg.js');}
        };
        </script>
```

I've also removed my `.htaccess` files from `wp-admin` and `wp-include` folders, but I'm still getting the error. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using your actual URL in this bit, is this the actual code you have?  You need to link to the actual JS file: `baseURL: "https://my-url/wp-includes/js/tinymce",`

Comment: @Bing yeah thats the actual url. there was an empty index.html in it which i removed too